# Error al crear paquete para la tienda Windows UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Internal compiler error: MCG0023:UnresolvableAssemblyReference Unresolvable assembly reference 'Assembly(Name=Java.Interop, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065)' found. Please check the references in your build system. A reference is either missing or an assembly is missing an expected type.

Me salta este error al intentar compilar la aplicación en modo Release. Se trata de una aplicación **Xamarin Classic**, y este error me aparace al compilar la aplicación **universal de Windows**(**UWP**). Toda la documentación que he leído habla de este error en Xamarin Android, pero nada en UWP.

He revisado el .csproj para comprobar que no tuviese referencias a Java. Estoy actualizado pero nada.

¿Alguien ha tenido algo parecido?
¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: A que te refieres con Xamarin Classic?

Comment: La aplicación está hecha con Xamarin, tiene app para Android, iOS y Windows. Está inciada con Classic, es decir, cada paquete de vistas es "nativo", diferente a si lo hiciese con Xamarin.Forms. Comparto todo el modelo y los ViewModels mediante una PCL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error lo he podido solucionar cambiando las opciones de compilación en Visual Studio 2017. En la configuración de Build he desmarcado la opción: Compile with .NET Native tool chain cuando el target de compilación es ARM.

Por si le sirve a alguien.

Comment: Recuerda marcar el check para aceptar la respuesta, así ayudas a mantener la salud del sitio mediante % de preguntas resueltas :D Como tú mismo la resolviste, espera 24 horas para que marques el check :D